# Play one video immediately after another one with `\usepackage{multimedia}`

Tags: beamer, packages, package-options, media9, multimedia

If I use `autostart` only `video4` plays, but the idea is to play all videos in order, i.e., first `video1`, then second `video2` immediately after `video1` finishes and so forth. Is that possible? I haven't found much documentation for the `\usepackage{multimedia}`, so not sure if it is possible.

Any ideas are welcomed, thanks in advance,

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \tiny\subfigure[video1]{\movie[height=3cm,width=4cm,poster,autostart]{}{video1.avi}}
        \quad
        \tiny\subfigure[video2]{\movie[height=3cm,width=4cm,poster,autostart]{}{video2.avi}}
        \\
        \tiny\subfigure[video3]{\movie[height=3cm,width=4cm,poster,autostart]{}{video3.avi}}
        \quad
        \tiny\subfigure[video4]{\movie[height=3cm,width=4cm,poster,autostart]{}{video4.avi}}
        \tiny\caption{Trying to play video1, then video2, then video3 and finally video4.}
    \end{figure}
```